# sliding sub-menu pure CSS

Tags: css, submenu

I have a problem with a sliding sub-menu in pure css.
I'm using css transition to animate the margin-top of the sub-menu for sliding it from the top of the page, i want it slide under the header background.
I've tried with a negative z-index but in this way the anchors of the sub-menu aren't clicckable.
So i've tried putting a span before the ul of the submenu with the background-attachment fixed, this is good if I change the width of the browser's window but is not good when i scroll the page down.
Any suggests?

The voice with the submenu is "Activitées"

[negative z-index solution](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/one.html)

[span overlayer solution](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/two.html)

Negative z-index solution submenu CSS code:

```
#main_menu ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
    min-width:160px;
    max-width:180px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px 0;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid #1c435e;
    margin-top:-500px;

    transition-property: margin-top; 
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;

    -webkit-transition-property: margin-top; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;

    -o-transition-property: margin-top;     
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;

    -moz-transition-property: margin-top;  
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#main_menu ul li:hover ul{margin-top:40px;}
```

Span overlayer solution CSS:

```
#main_menu ul li{
    position:relative;
}
#main_menu > ul > li > a{
    font-size:1.9em;
    color:#fff;
    padding:3px 8px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#main_menu ul li.selected a,#main_menu ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#main_menu ul > li > span{
    content:'';
    height:140px;
    width:180px;
    background:url("http://jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/css/img/bg_header.png") repeat-x fixed left top transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:-69px;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#main_menu ul li ul, #main_menu ul li ul li{display:block;}

#main_menu ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
z-index:0;
    min-width:160px;
    max-width:180px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px 0;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid #1c435e;
    margin-top:-500px;

    transition-property: margin-top;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;

    -webkit-transition-property: margin-top;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;

    -o-transition-property: margin-top;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;

    -moz-transition-property: margin-top;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#main_menu ul li:hover ul{margin-top:40px;}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code to reproduce the issue in the question itself.

Comment: please first you set background-color

Answer (score 0):

give some extra padding-bottom to your li element #main_menu, which will extend it downwards and keep your mouse-hover active, when user moves his mouse towards submenu.

this fix works for [Negative -index solution](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/one.html)

```
#main_menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

For second method, [Span Overlay method](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/two.html)

Give your **container overflow** property and remove that **background-attachment:fixed** from that **li span** , as its direct child **#menu_lang** and **#main_menu** has float property, which always creates some issue for its parent element.

```
.container {overflow:hidden}
```

or put your these both child elements in some another div and give it **overflow:hidden**

Comment: Ops sorry i don't know why on my example the anchor of the submenu working but here it doesn't work so i think the problem is another one?
I can't keep the submenu open and when i remove the animation the anchors aren't clicckable...
http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/adulti.html

Comment: @user3036737 I checked it on IE9 as well Chrome - the anchor tags are working fine. ! Though, they are known to create a problem when given negative z-index. ! But, this simple fix works for your code.!

Comment: You are not stupid, but please, avoid to use negative z-index values. It's very dangerous.

Comment: I don't know why on my example the negative z-index work and here on my project no!
http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/adulti.html

Comment: without negative z-index i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Why here: http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/one.html
negative z-index work
and here no?: http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/adulti.html

Comment: @user3036737 you can go for your span method, all you need to do is **remove that fixed property from background** of that **li** tag, and add `overflow:hidden` to your **.container** class.

Comment: @user3036737 on **line no: 76**  of **stile.css** you have commented 'z-index:2' value ! this is why, -ve z-index is not working there

Comment: with the span method if I use background-attachment: scroll when i resize the window the shape of the header's background don't fit with the shape of the span background

Comment: I've removed the z-index:2 on the line 76 but still don't work....
http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/index.html

Comment: @user3036737 don't remove it, uncomment it ! Sorry, I forgot to mention it..! I checked it works, when you uncomment it

Comment: i've tried to erase the section tag, and it works, so the problem is there but i don't have any z-index on this tag...

Comment: OK i've two tet page now, the first is with only the header tag, the second one have also a section tag, the first work the second no! I think is a problem of negative z-index that put the submenu under the section tag. I can't fix them: http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/test1.html http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/test2.html

Comment: Hi to everyone, so i've tried the negative z-index solution without success, if I can put the submenu under the header's background I can't go on the anchor and keep the submenu open. It work just if i remove all the section tag... http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/index-1.html

Comment: So i've tried also the span overlayer solution but the problem is when I decrease the width of the Borwser's window the indented shape of the header's background and the span's background don't fit so if the user's screen is larger or smaller they don't coincides...  http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/index-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use negative z-index, increase the other z-index instead. negative z-index makes some issues and it's not compatible with some old browsers like IE8.

The negative z-index solution it works for me in Firefox 40 but in some browsers maybe don't works.

You can use the span overlayed solution adding some pixels (2 pixels from border left and right) to the width or making `box-sizing:border-box` to include paddings in the width. So my suggestion is like this:

```
 #main_menu ul > li > span {
      width: 182px;
 }
```

### UPDATE

To fit the fake-span background you need to change the background property to this:

```
 #main_menu ul > li > span selector {
    background: url("http://jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/css/img/bg_header.png") repeat-x left top ;
  }
```

Comment: the problem is not on thw width, the problem is when you scroll the page and the indented shape of the header's background don't fit

Comment: So your problem is not here. Is in the background. If you change the background of your span, remove `fixed` value, it fits: `background: transparent url("http://jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/css/img/bg_header.png") repeat-x left top` in `#main_menu ul > li > span` selector

Comment: I want try to fix before the negative z-index ju st for understanding where is the bug then i'll use the span method fo browsers comptibility

Comment: Ok, it's your choice hahaha. You must to make experiments but I say to you that z-index negative values aren't recommended. I fight with it about 3 years ago, and I think that it works till the clients begin to report related bugs...

Comment: So i've tried also the span overlayer solution but the problem is when I decrease the width of the Borwser's window the indented shape of the header's background and the span's background don't fit so if the user's screen is larger or smaller they don't coincides... jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/index-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the span. You can simply animate the UL height. I have created a codepen. Please check it. Hope It will work for you.

```
#main_menu ul li:hover ul{margin-top:0; height: 290px;}
#main_menu ul li:hover ul:before{top:0;}
#main_menu ul li ul li{border-bottom:1px solid #7a9fb8;margin:0 10px;padding:10px;}
#main_menu ul li ul li:last-child {border-bottom:none;}
#main_menu ul li ul li a{font-size:1.6em;color:#1c435e;}
#main_menu ul li ul li a:hover{color:#7a9fb8;}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/rahuldsg/pen/JYjpax)

Comment: But the submenu is over the header's background

Comment: I just made some changes in CSS. Please check now.
http://codepen.io/rahuldsg/pen/JYjpax

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!!!**
I did a third version using a span inside the header with the width setted to 100% and the indented background image.
Than i've putted the span inside the li that contain the submenu just with a background-color.
No negative z-index just two span, the first for the indented shape the second one for cover the submenu sliding from the top.
**Header HTML code:**

```
<header>
    <span></span>
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="menu_lang">
            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="" title="fra" >fr</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="eng" >en</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="logo" href="" rel="home"></a>
        <nav id="main_menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="selected"><a href="index.html" rel="home">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Activitées</a>
                   <span></span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="adulti.html">Cours adultes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="giovani.html">Cours jeunes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="loc-esp.html">Location espace</a></li>
                        <li><a href="compleanni.html">Anniversaires</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contatti.html">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS code:**

```
header{
    width:100%;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#1C435E;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
header > span{
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url("http://jeanclaudechiementin.com/art-time/css/img/bg_header.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:-10px;
    left:0;
}
#main_menu ul li{
    padding-bottom:60px;
    position:relative;
}
#main_menu > ul > li > a{
    font-size:1.9em;
    color:#fff;
    padding:3px 8px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#main_menu ul > li > span{
    content:'';
    height:130px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#1C435E;
    position:absolute;
    top:-69px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
#main_menu ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    min-width:160px;
    max-width:180px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px 0;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid #1c435e;
    margin-top:-500px;

    transition-property: margin-top; 
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;

    -webkit-transition-property: margin-top;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;

    -o-transition-property: margin-top;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;

    -moz-transition-property: margin-top;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#main_menu ul li:hover ul{margin-top:40px;}
```

[>>Definitive solution](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test-submenu/index-3.html)
**I hope this can help someone else!!!**

Comment: There's just one little problem, when you stay on the span with the indented background the sub menu disappear because is over the li wth the submenu. I think there'are no solutions for this...

Comment: What do you think about it? Do you have any other solution?